Ubuntu 22.04 fstab settings don't completely "take"
The following fstab entries allowed rw access on my data drives and mounted them in /media:
UUID=1214119514117CC3                      /media/Expansion1 ntfs auto,nofail,noatime,rw,user,dev,umask=000,uid=noleks,gid=noleks 0  0
UUID=8EF6A334F6A31C09                      /media/Expansion2 ntfs auto,nofail,noatime,rw,user,dev,umask=000,uid=noleks,gid=noleks 0  0

Now for some reason in Ubuntu 22.04 they mount as ro.
I dual booted this drive.  I made sure that I turned of fast boot and shut down cleanly.
I have also confirmed that removing these entries allows the drives to mount in the wrong place (/media/noleks) but rw mode.
Is there an adjustment that can be made to the fstab entries to get things working again or is there some other setting I need to change?

I removed the fstab entries, rebooted, and let the system mount the drives.
These new entries work:
UUID=1214119514117CC3 /media/Expansion1 ntfs3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
UUID=8EF6A334F6A31C09 /media/Expansion2 ntfs3 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0

The filesystem type "ntfs3" seems to be the big change.
